# Getting invalid Zip files after sending to a client

Tags: c#, networking, zip

I'm trying to send a zip file from a server to client using TCP ports.
I'm creating a zip file in a server folder, reading it into a byte array, sending it to a connected client, writing the bytes into a file and storing it in a client folder. Currently the process is just on the same computer.

However, whenever the zip file is saved into the client folder, it's either an invalid zip or a zip with corrupted files. When this happens they'll have the exact same size as the zip file in the server folder, so I don't think I'm losing any bytes in the network transfer. The server zip file also works as expected, you are able to open and view contents in the folder.

The hashes between the client zip and the server zip are different. I've tested with regular .txt, .cs and .csv files, and those are sent and can be opened in the client folder. They have the same has as their server counterpart.

The zip file I'm sending just has a .csv, a .txt, and a .cs file in it.

This is my code

Server:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO.Compression;

String filename = "C:\\BabyServerZip\\ServerFiles.zip";

File.Delete("C:\\BabyServerZip\\ServerFiles.zip");
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:\\BabyServerSend", "C:\\BabyServerZip\\ServerFiles.zip");

IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint endpoint = new(ipAddress, 58008);
Socket listener = new(endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(endpoint);
listener.Listen();

var handler = await listener.AcceptAsync();
var buffer =  new byte[1024];

buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
handler.Send(buffer);
```

Client:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
String outputPath = "C:\\BabyClientReceive\\sent.zip";

IPHostEntry = ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
IPAddress serverIP = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint clientEnd = new(serverIP, 58008);
Socket clientSocket = new(clientEnd.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
clientSocket.ConnectAsync(clientEnd);

while (true)
{
   if (clientSocket.Available > 0)
   {
      using (StreamWriter fw = new StreamWriter(outputPath))
      {
         char[] response;
         do
         {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            int received = clientSocket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(buffer, 0, received);
            fw.Write(response, 0, received);
         while (response.Length == 1024);
         fw.Flush();
         fw.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing in order to correctly send zip files over a network? Why are the uncompressed files working correctly and the zip files breaking?

Comment: Your client code doesn't make any sense. Why are you trying to convert the ZIP file data (which is binary data) into ASCII text? Why? (o.O)??? (ASCII is encoding characters in 7 bits. In effect, your client shreds every received byte that has the highest bit, the 8th bit, set.)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Sounds like that's probably my problem them, I've been using the ASCII because that's what was working with the uncompressed files. Writing the buffer into the file was also giving me invalid zips. Am I supposed to use a different type of encoding?

Comment: "_Am I supposed to use a different type of encoding?_". No. A ZIP archive is not text data. It is binary data. You are supposed to use NO encoding at all...

Comment: Also, your while loop doesn't make sense on a logical level. If clientSocket.Receive receives less than buffer.Length bytes with more data still in transit, your code continues iterating the outer while loop, and testing with `clientSocket.Available > 0` could or could not be successful. But even if that check is sucessful then, you are then creating a new StreamWriter, overwriting all data that has been already received with the now incoming remaining data.

Comment: If you want to keep doing low-level TCP stuff with sockets, you have to program very defensively. Because, the behavior of data transmissions in a real-world situation through the internet, involving complex routes through different ISP's, home/office routers, etc... can be dramatically different from the "naive" case of transmitting over the local loopback device localhost/127.0.0.1 that doesn't involve any network infrastructure at all...

Comment: I second the comments above; there is a *lot* wrong with pretty much all the socket code. Writing proper socket applications is extremely difficult; I recommend using pretty much *any* alternative technology. E.g., self-hosted signalr.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue thanks to the tip from @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace.

StreamWriter is a text writer, and zip files are binary. Switching the StreamWriter for BinaryWriter fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your client code is all wrong. You are using a `StreamWriter` as if the Zip is text, but it's not, it's *binary*. Replacing it with a `BinaryWriter` is silly also, because that is primarily for writing custom binary formats bit by bit.

There are numerous other issues with the way you are handling this, as you need to expect that the response will not come as a single blob.

Instead you should not use raw sockets, but use `TcpClient`. You just need to copy the stream straight into a `FileStream`.

There are also missing `await` and you should use `IPAddress.Any` instead of `localhost`.

```cs
String outputPath = "C:\\BabyClientReceive\\sent.zip";
using TcpClient client = new();
await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Any, 58008);

using (var ns = client.GetStream())
using (var fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    await ns.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```